# How to check whether jenkins is fully up and running using webservice ?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, command-line-interface

I want to know , how to check whether jenkins is fully up and running using webservice ?

i want to use jenkins webservice to check this. Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to perform a simple HTTP get on the Jenkins server root URL. You get a successful status (200) if Jenkins is fully up. If it is not you'll get 503 - `Service Temporarily Unavailable` (or possibly other errors depending on specific situation).

From the command line you can use a tool such as [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to perform that request.

Answer (score 1):

Could also use curl:

```
while [[ $(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" http://server -o /dev/null) != "200" ]]; do
  sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers: If security is enabled, you will get HTTP 403 from the root URL. To get HTTP 200, you can check http://server/login.